# Can a 3-SAT Boolean Satisfiability clause be "directly" reduced to a 2-SAT problem?

Tags: logic, np-complete, satisfiability

*Definitions:*

[**SAT**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) is the problem "Given a propositional logic statement, does the statement have an assignment of its variables that result in the statement being true".

[**3-SAT**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#3-satisfiability) is a SAT problem, written as clauses with 3 variables or less. For example `((A or B or C) and (not B or not C))` has 2 clauses. `A`, `B` and `C` are boolean variables; "`or`" and "`and`" are the standard logical operators. This problem has at least one solution `(A, B, C) = (true, false, true)`.

[**2-SAT**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#2-satisfiability) is a SAT problem, written as clauses with 2 variables or less.

[We can reduce 2-SAT to the problem of finding a cycle in a directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implication_graph): We can create a vertex for each variable (and its negation). We write each clause `((A) or (B))` in implication form: `((A) or (B)) <=> ((not (not A)) or (B)) <=> ((not A) implies (B))`. We add a directed edge for each "implies" clause. The 2-SAT problem will be satisfied if and only if for all variables `X`, vertices `(X)` and `(not X)` are not contained in a cycle. (Equivalently, there is a path from `(X)` to `(not X)` and a path from `(not X)` to `(X)` if and only if there is a contradiction - that is, if the 2-SAT problem is not satisfied.)

---

**Can a 3-SAT clause be "directly" (defined in [3]) reduced to a 2-SAT problem?**

[1] 2-SAT is equivalent to "for some X, does the implication graph contain both paths from `(X)` to `(not X)` and from `(not X)` to `(X)`?

[2] In other words, a 2-SAT problem is satisfied if and only if 2 vertices in its implication graph contradict (are in the same cycle).

How, then, can there be a "direct" reduction from a 3-SAT clause to 2-SAT?

[3] If there's a "direct" reduction from a 3-SAT clause to 2-SAT, then, for each clause `D = (A or B or C)`, there will exist 3 vertices `A`, `B`, `C` in the 2-SAT implication graph such that the clause `D` is satisfied if and only if `(not ((not A) and (not B) and (not C)))` (which falsifies the clause).

[4] There are **3** variables involved there ([3]) in the satisfaction.

[5] A 2-SAT problem is satisfied, or not, based on **2** vertices ([2]).

[6] You can't encode "unsatisfy if and only if 3 variables contradict" into directed edges ("directly"). (A 2-SAT problem could have multiple pairs of contradicting vertices; each contradiction corresponds to a pair of vertices. You can't "fit" 3 "into" a pair.)

[7] Given [6], if a 3-SAT clause can be "directly" reduced to 2-SAT, then, it must not be one-to-one with the variables.

Therefore, a 3-SAT clause cannot be "directly" reduced to 2-SAT.

Answer (score 1):

No, a 3-CNF clause cannot be directly reduced to a 2-CNF clause.

2-SAT solutions all have the median property: You can take any three solutions, take the majority value of each variable and produce a fourth solution.  If a Boolean formula has three satisfying assignments that together do not have this property, then that formula cannot be represented as a conjunction of 2-CNF clauses.  As an example $(x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3)$ has among its satisfying assignments 100, 010 and 001.  Taking the majority value of each variable produces 000, which is not a satisfying assignment.  So $(x_1 \lor x_2 \lor x_3)$ cannot be equivalently represented as a 2-CNF clause.

Comment: Was there something wrong with my proof?